# How to run sql in sublime text 3?

Tags: sql, sublimetext3

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\xampp\\mysql\bin\\mysql.exe", "-u", "root", "-e", 
        "source $file", "-t"], "selector": "source.sql",    
}
```

i created build MYsql like the code above, after that i created database called bambang, import my sql file named hr.sql.

```
CREATE DATABASE bambang;
USE bambang;
source C:\Users\Mehong\Documents\export_mysql\hr.sql;
```

Then i want to show are tables in hr.sql with *SHOW tables* but i saw nothing.
i tried in my cmd and it worked. why couldn't i run it in sublime ?

```
CREATE DATABASE bambang;
USE bambang;
source C:\Users\Mehong\Documents\export_mysql\hr.sql;
SHOW tables;

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['C:\\xampp\\mysql\x08in\\mysql.exe', '-u', 'root', '-e', 'source C:\\Users\\Mehong\\Documents\\export_mysql\\mencoba.sql', '-t']]
[dir: C:\Users\Mehong\Documents\export_mysql]
[path: C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\Mehong\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
[Finished]
```

Comment: That error looks like the first item in the `cmd` (that points to `mysql.exe`) is referencing a file that doesn't exist. Does running this command manually from a command prompt work?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I had changed mysql.exe to mysql, and my sql program in sublime is work.